# Problem of requests package with Python version

Tags: python-requests

When I try to send a request via python3.6 to some urls, it waits until Timeout exception is raised( ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host={host}, port=443): Read timed out) . But when I try the same request via python2.7 it is successfully completed with status code: 200. Can you help me?

Version of Requests Package: 2.23.0

Sample Code:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.khaneyeshoma.ir/"
requests.get(url=url, timeout=10)
```

Thanks!

Comment: how you have installed requests??

Comment: by running this command in virtual environment: pip install requests==2.23.0

Answer (score 0):

sometimes problem occurs cuz of using timeout parameter try :

```
requests.get(url=url,)
```

Comment: after long time waiting it raises this error: ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Answer (score 0):

It think is because of the website you are trying to access. The request is correct, but it may need some extra headers.

If you try the request on other address it will work:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.google.com"
requests.get(url=url, timeout=10)
```

Response:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib.request with postman header, and you won't need timeout anymore:

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.khaneyeshoma.ir/"
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent':"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
    }
)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of a whitespace between the header field-name(access-control-expose-headers) and colon.  RFC 7230:

```
No whitespace is allowed between the header field-name and colon. In the past,
differences in the handling of such whitespace have led to security vulnerabilities 
in request routing and response handling. A server MUST reject any received request 
message that contains whitespace between a header field-name and colon with a 
response code of 400 (Bad Request). A proxy MUST remove any such whitespace from a
response message before forwarding the message downstream.
```